# Android Contacts Sync

Tags: android

I am new to the Android Development, Please tell me how to read contacts from Phone and how to add new Contact to the Phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the `android.provider.ContactsContract` class. Since it is very broad, I recommend you to first take a look at the SDK description of ContactsContract.RawContact. There you will find description with code snippets for basic operation on Contacts.

Also, take a look at the Android SDK code examples:

android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\SampleSyncAdapter\src\com\example\android\samplesync\platform\ContactOperations.java